# Calculation MOSFET max current needed for PCB + pulldown calculation?

Tags: mosfet

I would like to know if there is a calculation that allows me to look up at how much current my PCB would draw in the worse-case scenario if all my MOSFETs would have to change at the same time. In the PCB I use  11 IRLL014 in a SOT223, and 4 IRF3704 in TO 220.
https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/427/sihll014-1768836.pdf
http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3704.pdf
It would be fine if you say what I have to look at in the datasheets.

Another thing is to recalculate the pull-down resistors, what I would need to look at as they are right now with 10K they don't work right.

[image]

on the GAIN there are SSR and 12V,
SOURCE is gnd
GATE comes from the ESP32(ttl)

On the Load Side there are either

https://store.brewpi.com/featured/3-phase-solid-state-relay-ssr-20a

https://store.brewpi.com/featured/ssr-40a

https://store.brewpi.com/featured/td5-24v-pwm-brewing-pump

As you can see there is already a 10k Ohm pull down but it seems that this one doesn't work as the fet doesn't turn off all the time or delayed. Should I just put in a 100k/1k and check if it works or is there a way to calculate it?

Thanks !

Comment: A schematic fragment isn't very helpful. We need a lot more. Voltages, loads, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10k resistor is to ensure the mosfets are turned off during reset. In normal operation the gate should be actively driven high or low.

The IRll04 is a n-channel mosfet. The source goes to 0V, the drain goes to the load -. 12V goes to the other side of the load. To have it work as you've described requires the gate to be higher than 12V to turn it on - this would be a challenge with the ESP32.

Comment: Yes sorry, seems I misunderstood the scemantic a bit. There is 12vdc after the load (ssr) and the source will switch to the ground from the source if turned on over gate. They both work with ttl signal if I look at the datasheet. My question would be how to calculate the min and maximal current drawn at the gate if it switches or where can I find it.

Comment: In the datasheet for the FET you should find the gate capacitance, which will likely be of the order of tens of nanofarads and so the 10k pull-down will give a switch-off time of the order of hundreds of microseconds.  If you need a faster switch-off then you'll either need a lower value pull-down or better still drive the gate actively in both directions.